# These blinds rely on rechargeable battery power and "not internal house"

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say "[not internal house](https://querysprout.com/ikea-blinds/)" in "customers who purchase IKEA’s smart blinds do not need to have an electrician’s help with installing them, because these blinds rely on rechargeable battery power and "not internal house"? Also, is there another way to say it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is rather an odd way to express this.  From context, I know what it means but I would not use "internal house"

I would say that the blinds don't rely on "mains power" or "mains electricity". Or I might say that the blinds don't have to be "plugged in".

I think the word "mains" might be British English.

Comment: [Yes, "mains" is rather British.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity#Terminology)  Here in the US, I'd probably say "*household* current/electricity/power".

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can also say:

> ...the blinds rely on rechargeable battery power (Direct Current) and not the house's internal electric supply (Alternating Current).

Or you can include the actual voltage, which is substantially different.

> ...the blinds rely on 12 volts of rechargeable battery power, not the 120 volts or higher from the house's main electric supply.